# Como posso pegar o atributo src em uma Table cells Collection?

Tags: javascript, array, lógica, crud

Eu criei um input tipo "text" para exibir a url da imagem quando for colocada na função exibir a imagem que será editada, mas estou tendo problema na parte da edição, quando eu faço a escolha da coluna para editar, ela apresentar a seguinte situação:

```
<img id="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker2000.png">
```

Tem algum forma de puxar a imagem apenas pelo atributo "src"?
Lembrando que estou puxando a imagem desta forma:

```
document.getElementById("imagem").value = linha_selecionada.cells[1].innerHTML;
```

Ou seja, ela pegar todos os componentes que estão inseridos na tag. Gostaria de pegar apenas o que está dentro do src, existe alguma forma? Ou existe outra forma mais eficaz?

**Simplificado**

Estou cadastro a url da imagem, ela vai aparecer como imagem mesmo, mas quando ela retorna, ela vem com todos os atributos, estou querendo apenas o que contém dentro do "src" para que fosse editada.

**Função Exibir**

```
function insertNewRecord(data){
var tabela = document.getElementById("lista-produto").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var nova_linha = tabela.insertRow(tabela.length);

var celula_01 = nova_linha.insertCell(0);
celula_01.innerHTML = data.produto;

var celula_02 = nova_linha.insertCell(1);
celula_02.innerHTML = `<img id="img" src="${data.imagem}">`

var celula_03 = nova_linha.insertCell(2);
celula_03.innerHTML = data.descricao;

var celula_04 = nova_linha.insertCell(3);
celula_04.innerHTML = `
  <button class="btn btn-secondary m-1" onClick="onEdit(this)">editar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger m-1">excluir</button>
`}
```

**Função Exibir - Editar**

```
function onEdit (table) {
linha_selecionada = table.parentElement.parentElement;
document.getElementById("produto").value = linha_selecionada.cells[0];
document.getElementById("imagem").value = linha_selecionada.cells[1].innerHTML;
document.getElementById("descricao").value = linha_selecionada.cells[2].innerHTML; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas observações:

1. Dentro da função `insertNewRecord()` na linha `celula_02.innerHTML = ＇<img id="img" src="${data.imagem}">＇` você dá a entender que sua intenção que pretende criar várias linhas contendo cada uma um elemento `<img>` onde todos os elementos criados possuirão o mesmo atributo [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).
   O atributo global id define um identificador exclusivo que **deve ser único por todo o documento**.
2. Dentro da função `onEdit()` na linha `linha_selecionada = table.parentElement.parentElement;` não me está claro o método de seleção de linha da tabela pois a propriedade de leitura [`Node.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) retorna o nó pai do elemento DOM, assim me causando dificuldades em compreender como o ancestral do ancestral da tabela serve para selecionar uma linha interna a tabela.

Passadas as observações, você pode obter o URL de um elemento `<img>` por meio de [interface DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) utilizando a propriedade [`HTMLImageElement.src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/src) que reflete o [atributo HTML src](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-src).
Dentro da célula selecionada da linha selecionada você pode utilizar o método [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) para obter a referência ao elemento `<img>` dentro dessa célula fazer a leitura da propriedade `HTMLImageElement.src`.

```js
//Seleciona os elementos do exemplo.
const tabela = document.getElementById("tabela");
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const button = document.getElementById("button");

//Adiciona um evento click ao botão
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const linha_selecionada = tabela.rows[0];                          // Seleciona a primeira linha da tabela.
  input.value = linha_selecionada.cells[1].querySelector("img").src; // Seleciona a segunda célula da linha selecionada, obtém a referência para o primeiro elemento <img> dentro da célula, lê a URL do <img> e atribui seu valor ao input. 
});
```

```html
<table id="tabela">
  <tr>
    <td>imagem de exemplo</td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker2000.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="text" id="input" size="50">
<button id="button">Clique</button>
```